# Chrome "continue where you left off" not working after using "create shortcut" feature

Tags: google-chrome

I have successfully uses Chrome's "continue where you left off" feature for years. However, I've recently made use of the "create shortcut" feature (menu --> more tools --> create shortcut), in which you can save a webpage as a standalone link on your desktop. For this I use the "open in new window" option, so that I can open that webpage like a standalone web app (this is useful for things like Trello which doesn't have a windows app for example).

However, it appears that this confuses the the "continue where I left off" feature... If I open Chrome and my Trello "web app" (essentially another Chrome window) and then close them, when I reopen Chrome I get the new tab page instead of the tabs I had open. It seems the problem is the web app, in that Chrome sees that as my last Chrome window, with only that one tab, and my other Chrome window (which is actually for browsing, with open tabs) gets disregarded.

Any ideas on how to get around this? Perhaps some way for Chrome to prioritise one window over another when saving my current tabs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here...

I have a permanent Google Calendar and Google Keep window/desktop app open.

I have used that for years with just a Google Keep app/window on my desktop without any problem. I have recently added a Google Calendar app/window and that broke everything :(

Guess having a chrome desktop app open messes everything with the browser now :(

Every time I close my browser will several tabs open, when I reopen it only displays one empty blank tab as if the "continue where I left off" wasn't activated.

I think the issue is not linked to the use of the "create shortcut" link but simply having an app open on the desktop... Because if I close those windows/chrome based desktop apps *before* closing the browser, then it remembers the open tabs...

Couldn't find a way to solve the problem, so I've deleted the "chrome based desktop apps" and solved the problem that way. With only the browser, chrome keeps track of the open tabs when you close the browser and reopens them fine at the next session....

As for the desktop app/websites like keep and calendar I use, I simply open them using the Chromium version of Edge... Works perfectly fine for me and I guess it doesn't make a big difference system wise...

[How to Use Web Apps with New Chromium Edge on Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/using-web-apps-new-chromium-edge-windows-10/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use another browser to handle my web apps. Much appreciated! This is probably the best possible workaround at present.